# Prolog - Find the first solution and stop searching

Tags: prolog

I am learning programming in Prolog and have a problem with a rule, it must search for the solution and once it is found, it must to do "nothing". But it have failed and given me more than one solution. I tried to do something like this:

```
% here the solution is already found and there's nothing to be done.
findsolution:-
       solution(X).

% trying to find the solution and use assert/1 if it was found. 
 findsolution:-
        do_something, 
        do_whatever, 
        assert(solution(X)).
```

If the solution was not found, the first rule fails and the backtracking will try the second implementation of the rule . If the second find the solution, the first rule must succeed, the backtracking is not necessary anymore when I call 'findsolution/0' again only the first rule will be queried. My intent is to be efficient, preventing unnecessary queries, because I know there only one solution, just don't know what. I'm grateful.

P.S. the context of my program is not the same here, it is to simplify. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to stop the search, then what you must do is avoid (controlling) backtracking using the cut predicate, check the [docs](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse44).
In this case what you need to do basically is to avoid backtracking in your first clause, using this cut (!) predicate:

```
findsolution:- solution(X), !.
```

Comment: It is better style to use `once/1` because its effect is more local: `once(solution(X))`.

Comment: What a coincidence, today I used the predicate cut and it did not work. I think it's because the rule has another internal recursive rule and that is failing to be asserting two or more "solutions" at a time, but not sure. Anyway, I'll keep working on it, trying to figure out what is wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: Internal cuts won't have any effect on this rule. After the goal `solution(X)` success, and the cut goal is reached, there will be no backtracking over `solution(x)` goal.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for my delay, I was very busy. After some changes in the internal rule everything works fine. Your help was useful in other problem that I found. Thanks you so much!